# Unable to insert to the MongoDB instance from different files in a single project

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have made a basic skeleton of a typescript project here: https://github.com/xameeramir/instruments-admin

The mongoose connection is made from the [index.ts file](https://github.com/xameeramir/instruments-admin/blob/master/src/index.ts):

```
require('dotenv').config();
import express from "express";
const app = express();
const port = 8080; // default port to listen
import routes from "./routes";
import { connectToTheDatabase } from './mongooseUtility';

// define a route handler for the default home page
app.get("/status", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Instruments admin functionalities available!");
});

connectToTheDatabase();

app.use(routes);

// start the Express server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Instruments admin functionalities available at PORT ${port}`);
});
```

In the [all-tradeables.controller.ts](https://github.com/xameeramir/instruments-admin/blob/master/src/all-tradeables/all-tradeables.controller.ts), I'm calling `InstrumentModel.insertMany`.

Now, for some unknown reasons, the insertion is not happening. When I go to the MongoDB instance, I don't see any document inserted.

I have looked around the internet and I don't see any mistake in the code. Can someone please help me understand why the insertion is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was you were returning model without mongo instance. 
  Solution goes here: 
  replace all-tradeables.model.ts content with the following:

```
// import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
    import { Schema, Model, model } from 'mongoose';
    const mongooseInstance = require("mongoose");
    let connString = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbnamegoeshere';

    mongooseInstance.connect(connString, {useNewUrlParser: true});

    // define Schema
    let InstrumentSchema = new Schema({
        instrument_token: Number,
        exchange_token: Number,
        tradingsymbol: String,
        name: String,
        last_price: Number,
        expiry: Date,
        strike: Number,
        tick_size: Number,
        lot_size: Number,
        instrument_type: String,
        segment: String,
        exchange: String
    });

    // compile schema to model
    export const InstrumentModel = mongooseInstance.model('Instrument', InstrumentSchema);

    export const storeAllInstruments = (InstrumentsData: any) => {

        // return (() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        })
        // })();


    }
```

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it worked for you?

Comment: I have made one connection in the index.ts file. Generally, I should be able to re-use the same connection right?

Comment: whatever change i made that is the way to use mongoose model.